# On Qt how do I set line spacing on a Tree Widget?

Tags: qt, fonts, tree

On a word processor you can set 1.5 line spacing or double line spacing - I want to do a similar thing with QTreeWidgetItem.  I don't want to increase the size of the font, that would make the letters bigger.  I want more space between the lines it displays.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [stylesheet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtreeview).

Do something like this:

```
QTreeWidget::item {
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

It will add spaces inside child elements.

You can also use `margin` instead of `padding` to add spaces outside of element.

Comment: @Clive Could you please accept this answer if it was helpful?